# Add indent if text overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to show rest of `text` if it overflow via `text-indent` on `hover`, here is what i have tried so far:

```js
$('.all-items').each(function() {
  var indentSize = '-' + $(this).width + 'px';
  $(this).on('mouseenter', function() {

    console.log('a width:' + $(this).find('a').innerWidth());
    console.log('li width:' + $(this).innerWidth());

    if ($(this).find('a').innerWidth() > $(this).innerWidth()) {
      $(this).css('textIndent', indentSize);
    }
  });

  $(this).on('mouseout', function() {
    if ($(this).find('a').innerWidth() > $(this).innerWidth()) {
      $(this).css('textIndent', '0px');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.all-items {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s background ease;
  transition: .3s color ease;
  transition: 3s text-indent ease;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

</ul>
```

The logic is if `a` `width` higher than `li` `width` that's mean text overflowed, but this logic not working. any idea?

Comment: what about making a:hover to be position: absolute; ?
it should overflow container but not breaking/shifting anything else

Comment: @skyboyer any demo? but it has a good transition.. if it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after?

```js
$('.all-items').each(function() {
  var li = $(this),
    link = li.children('a').eq(0),
    liWidth = li.width(),
    linkWidth = link.width();

  if (linkWidth > liWidth) {
    var width = liWidth - linkWidth - 5; // get indent distance (added 5 for safety)
    link.data('width', width + 'px');

    li.on('mouseenter', function() {
      link.css('text-indent', link.data('width'));
    });

    li.on('mouseleave', function() {
      link.css('text-indent', 0);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.all-items {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.all-items>a {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .3s background ease;
  transition: .3s color ease;
  transition: 3s text-indent ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way</a></li>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. just a transition need. to show rest of text smoothly.

Comment: See edit - it's because you had the transition on the li but applied the indent to the anchor

Comment: Thanks, but I like to know what was the problem with my code? any note?

Comment: I think it's that you wasn't calculating the indent size properly - you seem to indent it the size of the li rather than the overflow amount and you had a couple of syntax errors in your js.  If you press f12 in your browser, you can look at your console to see any errors

Comment: Are you sure about syntax errors ? i don't see anything, not in my project, not here.. / Thanks at all

Comment: Ah perhaps it's not a syntax error as console isn't logging it but `$(this).width` should be a function `$(this).width()` so will be returning the wrong value here

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `each` loop and change `$(this).width` to `$(this).width()`

```js
  $('.all-items').on('mouseover', function() {
    var indentSize = $(this).width() + 'px';
    console.log('a width:' + $(this).find('a').innerWidth());
    console.log('li width:' + $(this).innerWidth());
    $(this).css('textIndent', indentSize);
    if ($(this).find('a').innerWidth() > $(this).innerWidth()) {
          $(this).css('textIndent', indentSize);
    }
  });

  $('.all-items').on('mouseout', function() {
    if ($(this).find('a').innerWidth() > $(this).innerWidth()) {
      $(this).css('textIndent', '0px');
    }
  });
```

```css
.all-items {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s background ease;
  transition: .3s color ease;
  transition: 3s text-indent ease;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

  <li class="first-level all-items" data-val="1"><a style="text-indent: 0px;">Easiest way to keep your customers in the loop about your product</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is showing element on `:hover` with `position: absolute`

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.4em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
}
span:hover {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><span>Testing long long long line</span></li>
<li><span>Another long long text</span></li>
</ul>
```